# Is it possible to change the IOS permission dialog UIButton tint color?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application and it has a different tint colour/color as apposed to the standard Apple Blue.

Is it possible to change the tint colour/color of the standard Permission Dialogs *(e.g. Push permissions dialog)* so that the dialogs appear to fit the rest of the applications theme?

I have tried a couple of things but none of them seem to work for me, currently testing on an emulator which I believe should be ok for this purpose.

Here are the things I have tried:

```
 [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

 [[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

 [_window setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: I doubt it and even if you did it may get your app rejected.  The idea is that it is important for the use to realise that the system is informing you that the app wants to do something and not just some alert that the app itself is using.

Answer (score 4):

[Uploader of Truth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8111753/upholder-of-truth) is absolutely right: You can't *actually* change system UI messages for a reason. They're meant to signal to the user that something important needs their attention. Modifying that not only would disrupt Apple's UI environment homogeneousness (sort of speak) but it would also cover an important system message as one of your own which more likely than not get your app rejected.

I recommend you take a look at [this article](http://babich.biz/mobile-ux-design-the-right-ways-to-ask-users-for-permissions/). It really helped me a lot with this same issue.

Comment: I believe those alerts are presented by a outside iOS process to that you literally cannot alter the presentation even if you wanted to use dirty tricks. App would definitely get rejected, and for good reason. What if you presented an In-App Purchase dialog and changed the price from $9999 to 0.99?

Comment: Did you find my explanation useful @Wayne?

Comment: Hi, I understand that one cannot change the looks - BUT then I would also discourage the use of other colours for your action buttons. Rather stick to the stock standard blue, else you would not be able to have a 100% look and feel throughout your application. An example of this could be to call a number when pressing a "Green call button" in your app, "green tint/the colour of your app"; Apple will then present another dialog to confirm this action using their blue tint colours. This results in both  Green and Blue tint in your Applications.

Answer (score -1):

The color of the action buttons in "AlertViews" is determined by iOS. Especially in the system permission dialogs.

In your own `UIAlertViewController` you can set the style of an Action which then determines the color. `default` is blue, `cancel` is blue with a lighter font and `destructive` is red.

See [UIAlertActionStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertactionstyle)